# Why do I need to input a non-char value twice to end the program

Tags: c++

I have some code that asks the user to enter an alphanumeric char, and if they enter something else (eg. @,#,$) it will ask again to enter an alphanumeric char.
For some reason I need to enter a non-alphanumeric character twice before it will accept it. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

void get_option(char& input, string msg) {
    string clear_input;
    bool isletter;
    bool isnumber;
    bool test = 0;
    while (test == 0) {
        cout << msg;
        cin >> input;
        isletter = isalpha(input);
        isnumber = isdigit(input);
        if (isletter == 0 && isnumber == 0) {
            cin.clear();
            cin >> clear_input;
            cout << input << endl << isnumber << endl << isletter << endl;
            test = 0;
        }
        else if (isletter == 1 || isnumber == 1) {
            test = 1;
        }

    }
}

int main() {
    char input;
    string msg = "Please enter an alphanumeric char: ";
    get_option(input, msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you have the line `cin >> clear_input` in the case where the user doesn't enter an alphanumeric character? This will wait for further input from the user.

Comment: Don't compare booleans to `0` and `1`. Write `if (!isletter && !isnumber) ...` and `if (isletter || isnumber) ...`. (And don't assign `0` and `1` to them either. Use `false` and `true`.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and answer to my question. Im still a noob at C++ and I appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the line `cin >> clear_input;`, for which I see absolutely no purpose. Remove that line (and the declaration of `clear_input` as for that matter).

Comment: Ahhh thanks for that. It was left over code from other code I was using and I didn't even think about it. Cheers